# Filter over duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, subquery, window-functions

I'm trying to identify a distinct list of `person_id` that have the same `account_id` as another person.

The caveat is the `person_id` who was last given the overlapping `account_id` should not be included in that list.

```
        id          person_id     account_id
   +------------------------------------------+
   |            |             |               |
   |     1      |     1       |      10       |
   +------------------------------------------+
   |            |             |               |
   |     2      |     2       |      10       |
   +------------------------------------------+
   |            |             |               |
   |     3      |     3       |      11       |
   +------------------------------------------+
```

**please note**: this is a slightly simplified example not to be taken too literally.

---

**This is the query I currently have**

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(person_id, ',')
FROM accounts_map
WHERE created_at > '2001-01-10' -- ignore records smaller than 2001-01-10
GROUP BY account_id -- group by account id
HAVING count(*) > 1 -- any account that have multiple matches
```

**What I can't figure out is**

1. How for each account_id match overlap, exclude the latest record
2. How to ignore records that have account_id marked as null, somehow <> NULL is not working

```
CREATE TABLE accounts_map
    ([id] int, [person_id] int, [account_id] int, [created_at] DATETIME)
;

INSERT INTO accounts_map
    ([id], [person_id], [account_id], [created_at])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 10, '2001-01-10'),
    (2, 1, 11, '2001-01-10'),
    (2, 1, 12, '2001-01-10'),

    (3, 2, 20, '2019-01-11'),
    (4, 2, 21, '2019-01-11'),
    (5, 2, 22, '2019-01-11'),

    (3, 3, 30, '2019-01-12'),
    (4, 3, 31, '2019-01-12'),
    (5, 3, 32, '2019-01-12'),

    -- same account ids as records with id (1,2,3) but inserted in different order
    (6, 4, 12, '2019-01-13'),
    (7, 4, 11, '2019-01-13'),
    (8, 4, 10, '2019-01-13'),

    -- same account ids as records with id (3,4,5)
    (9, 5, 20, '2019-01-14'),
    (10, 5, 21, '2019-01-14'),
    (11, 5, 22, '2019-01-14'),

    -- same account ids as records with id (9,10,11)
    (12, 6, 20, '2019-01-15'),
    (13, 6, 21, '2019-01-15'),
    (14, 6, 22, '2019-01-15')
;
```

**expected output**

```
id
---
1 (not expected if date range cutoff specified) created_at > '2001-01-10'
2
4 (not expected if date range cutoff specified) created_at > '2001-01-10'
5
```

If it has an account that overlaps, the latest user who was granted the account becomes the valid one corrupting the old ones.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f53e5/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a subqueryn you can do a window count within groups of records sharing the same `account_id` and use `row_number()` to rank them by date. Then the outer query filters on records whose window count is greater than 1 and returns all records but the latest:

```
select person_id, account_id, created_at
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by account_id order by created_at desc) rn,
        count(*) over(partition by account_id) cnt
    from accounts_map t
) t
where cnt > 1 and rn > 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=974eb026fd0eca3cdbb432ba6d9212c7)**:

```
person_id | account_id | created_at         
--------: | ---------: | :------------------
        1 |         10 | 10/01/2001 00:00:00
        1 |         11 | 10/01/2001 00:00:00
        1 |         12 | 10/01/2001 00:00:00
        5 |         20 | 14/01/2019 00:00:00
        2 |         20 | 11/01/2019 00:00:00
        5 |         21 | 14/01/2019 00:00:00
        2 |         21 | 11/01/2019 00:00:00
        5 |         22 | 14/01/2019 00:00:00
        2 |         22 | 11/01/2019 00:00:00
```

Note: you provided sample data but unfortunately not the associated expected results, for us to validate the output of the query.

Comment: whoops sorry let me update that! thanks very much for this btw! I'm trying to go through it and understand it right now

Comment: note how can I exclude records with account_id null? If I add account_id <> NULL all records dissapears

Comment: @user391986: there is no such record in your sample data... But anyway, you could simply add `WHERE account_id IS NOT NULL` in the subquery. To check for nullness, you need special sytanx `IS [NOT] NULL`, not equality/inequality.

Comment: That's true apologies! I was trying to simplify a pretty complex example into something simpler. I really appreciate your help this is fantastic and I did not know about partitions!

Comment: Welcome @user391986! Window functions are so useful in SQL, you want to learn about them...